# How to use capacitor as battery in razor?

Tags: batteries, capacitor

I have an old razor machine Philips 1304, it's circuit is broken, all I have is motor, housing ,blades and AC Adaptor.

So the question is how to use it just via power ? I can use capacitor only and don't have access to battery, according to the cover it's 4.4v AC

via AC Adaptor it's too weak, maybe because the lack of backup power like capacitor or battery.

so any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Find out what circuit used to be there and re-create that. If you think a capacitor is enough to store energy for such a motor then you have a lot to learn. You can buy a new razor for a couple of $ even used 1304 razors are cheap so what is the point of trying to get this thing to work.

Comment: thnx for your reply, I know it's cheap I'm just curious how is it possible.

Comment: No. That will not work.

Answer (score 4):

> - so any help will be appreciated
> - via AC Adaptor it's too weak, maybe because the lack of backup power
>     like capacitor

For the sake of argument, say the battery was 4 volts and delivered 250 mA to the motor during the minute that you are shaving. That's 1 watt for 60 seconds or a total energy of 60 joules.

A 1 farad capacitor charged to 4 volts has an energy of \$\dfrac{CV^2}{2}\$ = 8 joules.

But it's a little more complex than that because you realistically don't want the voltage to deplete below 3 volts or you motor isn't going to turn and the equation above is for full depletion energy. So, you want to leave 4.5 joules left inside the capacitor to avoid dropping below 3 volts.

If you had a 20 farad capacitor charged to 4 volts, energy aka work or W = 160 joules and at 3 volts it's 90 joules so that would be about right for your application - 70 joules of energy is bigger than that energy needed to take a shave (60 joules by my reckoning).

The next trouble is finding a 20 farad, 4 volt capacitor. The nearest I could find is too low in voltage so, you'd need to have two in series of 40 farads each. Then you have the problem of balance charging super capacitors in series (not trivial): -

[image]

These cost £5.84 each in Farnell. Your choice.

Comment: thanx for your nice answer, I'll check it out and will notify you , rep ++

Comment: @Freeman Please "accept" the answer if it is useful for you.

Comment: first of all I have to check if it will work I defiantly will !